# Knockout js add a new list

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to create a form with a list which adds a list dynamically!

However I just can't get my add function working and it keep complains that my list is not defined.

Here is my viewmodel in jave script

```
function DeliveryCategoryViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.DeliveryCategory = ko.observable(new DeliveryCategory(1, "new Name", [new DeliveryOption("first"), new DeliveryOption("second")]));

    self.addDeliveryOptions = function () {
        self.DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption("new Option"));
    }

    self.removeDeliveryOptions = function (option) {
        self.DeliveryCategory.remove(option);
    }

}
```

and these are actual model which holds the data

```
function DeliveryCategory(id, name, option) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.DeliveryOptions = ko.observableArray(option);

}

function DeliveryOption(name) {


    this.Id = "2";
        this.Name = name;
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(new DeliveryCategoryViewModel());
});
```

This is my form

```
<div id="newDelCategory">
        <input data-bind="value:DeliveryCategory().Id" type="hidden" />
        <label class="newDelCategoryLabel">New delivery category name: </label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:DeliveryCategory().Name" class="newDelCategoryText" id="newDelCategoryText" placeholder="Delivery category name" />
</div>

<div id="addOption">
    <a id="addOptionLink" href="#" data-bind="click:addDeliveryOptions" class="link">+Add delivery option</a>
</div>

<div id="deliveryOptionContent" data-bind="foreach: DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions">
    <div class="newDelOption">
        <input data-bind="value:$data.Id" type="hidden" />
        <div class="divider"></div>

        <label class="newDelOptionLabel">New delivery option name: </label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Name" class="categoryName" id="newDelOptionText" placeholder="Delivery option name" />
        <a id="removeOptionLink" data-bind="click:$parent.removeDeliveryOptions" class="link removeOptionLink">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to click click:addDeliveryOptions, it return on Firebug console.

```
TypeError: self.DeliveryCategory.DeliveryOptions is undefined
self.DeliveryCategory.DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption("new Option"));
```

I tried different things such as click:$root.addDeliveryOptions, and also tried to add addDeliveryOptions function as a prototype (e.g. DeliveryCategory.prototype.addDeliveryOptions(...)) and still getting Typeerror...

Is it because DeliveryOptions is not initialised? I expected that it would be when DeliveryCategory is initialised from the DeliveryCategoryViewModel() ...

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Small Oversight. Easy Fix.

**You were calling `push` and `remove` off the observable array from the view model but it does *not* exists as a direct member of the view model.**

This is because you never add the observable array directly to this view model. You use a constructor to create an object to observe with `DeliveryCategory`. One of the properties on that object is an observable array `DeliveryOptions`. To get access to the observable array from this scope, you have to evaluate `DeliveryCategory` to get access to it's property `DeliveryOptions` before you run any array methods. So, instead of this:

```
self.addDeliveryOptions = function () {
    self.DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption("new Option"));
}

self.removeDeliveryOptions = function (option) {
    self.DeliveryCategory.remove(option);
}
```

### The Solution:

```
self.addDeliveryOptions = function() {
    self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption("new Option"));
}

self.removeDeliveryOptions = function(option) {
    self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.remove(option);
}
```

See the snippet below

```js
function DeliveryCategoryViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.DeliveryCategory = ko.observable(new DeliveryCategory(1, "new Name", [new DeliveryOption("first"), new DeliveryOption("second")]));
  self.addDeliveryOptions = function() {
    self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption("new Option"));
  }

  self.removeDeliveryOptions = function(option) {
    self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.remove(option);
  }

}

function DeliveryCategory(id, name, option) {
  this.Id = id;
  this.Name = name;
  this.DeliveryOptions = ko.observableArray(option);

}

function DeliveryOption(name) {


  this.Id = "2";
  this.Name = name;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  ko.applyBindings(new DeliveryCategoryViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDelCategory">
  <input data-bind="value:DeliveryCategory().Id" type="hidden" />
  <label class="newDelCategoryLabel">New delivery category name:</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:DeliveryCategory().Name" class="newDelCategoryText" id="newDelCategoryText" placeholder="Delivery category name" />
</div>

<div id="addOption">
  <a id="addOptionLink" href="#" data-bind="click:addDeliveryOptions" class="link">+Add delivery option</a>
</div>

<div id="deliveryOptionContent" data-bind="foreach: DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions">
  <div class="newDelOption">
    <input data-bind="value:$data.Id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="divider"></div>

    <label class="newDelOptionLabel">New delivery option name:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Name" class="categoryName" id="newDelOptionText" placeholder="Delivery option name" />
    <a href="#" id="removeOptionLink" data-bind="click:$parent.removeDeliveryOptions" class="link removeOptionLink">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!!  I dived into knockout js few weeks ago and this is the explanation just what I needed!! Thanks a lot